# Get height of ScrollView hidden part

Tags: android, scrollview

Imagine a situation when screen is at middle of `ScrollView`. Is it possible to get height in pixels of hidden part at top?

[image]

It is possible to get height of visible screen part:

```
 Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
 mScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
```

Possible to get height of `ScrollView` by getting it's child height:

```
 int mScrollViewHeight = mScrollView.getHeight();
```

**But how do I determine height of that hidden part?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mScrollView.getScrollY();` returns the scrolled top position of this view which is the height of the "hidden" part at the top.

Comment: hello, i want to get visible height at the bottom, but still didn't found solution

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to first get the device height.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Then, get the top height of the visible Container.
Let's say your visible container is **RelativeLayout** which is referenced in your Activity class or in Fragment class as **mVisibleConatiner**.

```
int topHeight = mVisibleConatiner.getTop();
```

And then, the difference of these two will be your hidden part height.

```
int hiddenPartHeightInPx = height - topHeight;
```

Never, tried though, but it should work.

Comment: But, I guess @Rob solution, is more appropriate here, you don't have to write all the boilerplate codes.

Comment: Yea, Rob's solution works simply and correct. Thanks for alternative solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On My .xml file i put it like this
**viewContentView(LinearLayout) -> inside of -> mainScrollView**

[image: Scrollview format]

Then inside of my class i declare it like so

```
    final LinearLayout viewContentView = findViewById(R.id.viewContentView);
    final ScrollView mainScrollView = findViewById(R.id.mainScrollView);
    mainScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollY = mainScrollView.getScrollY(); // For ScrollView
            int scrollX = mainScrollView.getScrollX(); // For HorizontalScrollView
            Log.d("mainScrollView", "mainScrollView x: "+scrollX +"  || y: "+scrollY);
            Log.d("mainScrollView", "mainScrollView y: "+(viewContentView.getHeight() - mainScrollView.getBottom()));
            if(scrollY == 0){ //scroll to TOP
                viewpager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else if(scrollY == (viewContentView.getHeight() - mainScrollView.getBottom())){ //scroll to Bottom
                viewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```